# Fastest way to count frequencies of ordered list entries

Tags: python, iteration, counting

I'm counting the occurrences of non-overlapping grouped subsequences of length `i` in a binary list, so for example if I have a list:
`[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`, I want to count occurrences of `[0,0]` (one), `[0,1]` (two), `[1,0]` (one), `[1,1]` (one).

I have created a function that accomplishes this (see below). However, I would like to see if there is anything that can be done to speed up the execution time of the function. I've already got it to be pretty quick (over previous versions of the same function), and it currently takes about ~0.03 seconds for a list of length=100,000 and i=2, and about 30 seconds for a list of length=100,000,000 and i=2. (This is a seemingly linear increase in time in relation to sequence length). However, my end goal is to do this with functions for multiple values of `i`, with sequences of lengths near 15 billion. Which, assuming linearity holds, would take about 4.2 hours for just `i`=2 (a higher value of `i` take longer as it has to count more unique subsequences).

I unsure if there is much more speed that can be gained here(at least, while still working in python), but I am open to suggestions on how to accomplish this faster (with any method or language)?

```
def subseq_counter(i,l):
    """counts the frequency of unique, non-overlapping, grouped subsequences of length i in a binary list l"""
    grouped = [str(l[k:k + i]) for k in range(0, len(l), i)] 
    #groups terms into i length subsequences
    if len(grouped[len(grouped) - 1]) != len(grouped[0]):
        grouped.pop(len(grouped) - 1)
    #removes any subsequences at the end that are not of length i
    grouped_sort = sorted(grouped) 
    #necesary so as to make sure the output frequencies correlate to the ascending binary order of the subsequences
    grouped_sort_values = Counter(grouped_sort).values() 
    # counts the elements' frequency
    freq_list = list(grouped_sort_values)
    return freq_list
```

I know that a marginally faster execution time can be obtained by removing the `grouped_sorted` line, however, I need to be able to access the frequencies in correlation to the ascening binary order of the subsequences (so for `i`=2 that would be `[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]`) and have not figured about a better way around this.

Comment: Why do you even build such lists with billions of ones and zeros in the first place? Where does that come from, and what else are you doing with it other than this counting?

Comment: How large does your `i` get?

Comment: @KellyBundy for my desired length, `i`=5 is the largest it would get. As for the purpose, it is for use within a larger battery of statistical analysis tests to be applied to the output of a quantum physics experiment.

Comment: And those other tests need this exact format? It's really inefficient. I'd probably at least use a `bytearray` instead.

Comment: @KellyBundy Not necessarily, that's just how they had been set up (which could be changed), and the execution time bottleneck was this function, so therefore my query just talking about this task.

Comment: Dangit, zipping the repeated list iterator is so darn fast that I have not been able to beat it with any (pure Python) `bytearray` solution after all, so I might have to partially take that back. I have only tried much smaller lists, though (length=1,000,000), perhaps `bytearray`'s smaller memory size would give it an advantage at your scale. Or it might be good in combination with NumPy, haven't tried that. I did write a NumPy solution a bit faster than Colim's and of course also didn't waste time in my zip-solution like Paul did, so mine's a bit faster than theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if is faster, but try

```
import numpy as np

# create data
bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10000)


def subseq_counter(i: int, l: np.array):
    """
    Counts the number of subsequences of length l in the array i
    """
    # the list l is reshaped as a matrix of i columns, and
    # matrix-multiplied by the binary weigts "power of 2"
    #           |  [[2**2],
    #           |   [2**1],
    #           |   [2**0]]
    #           |____________________
    # [[1,0,1], | 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 5
    #  [0,1,0], | 0*4 + 1*2 + 0*1 = 2
    #  ...,     | ....
    #  [1,1,1]] | 1*4 + 1*2 + 1*1 = 7
    iBits = l[:i*(l.size//i)].reshape(-1, i)@(2**np.arange(i-1,-1,-1).T)

    unique, counts = np.unique(iBits, return_counts=True)

    print(f"Counts for {i} bits:")
    for u, c in zip(unique, counts):
        print(f"{u:0{i}b}:{c}")
        
    return unique, counts

subseq_counter(2,bits)
subseq_counter(3,bits)


>>> Counts for 2 bits:
>>> 00:1264
>>> 01:1279
>>> 10:1237
>>> 11:1220
>>> Counts for 3 bits:
>>> 000:425
>>> 001:429
>>> 010:411
>>> 011:395
>>> 100:437
>>> 101:412
>>> 110:407
>>> 111:417
```

what it does is to reshape the list into an array of n rows by `i` columns, and converting to integer by multiplying by `2**n`, converting `00 to 0`, `01 to 1`, `10 to 2` and `11 to 3`, then doing the counting with `np.unique()`

Comment: This is promising! Not including the time to generate the data, this method handled a sequence of length =100,000,000 in about 1.5 seconds! However, I'm not familiar with these methods, how would one generalize this to different values if `i`?

Comment: I made an edit for i length bits

Comment: @YaGoiRoot 1.5 seconds, really? Can it even do the conversion from list to array in that time?

Comment: @KellyBundy As I said, the 1.5 seconds was not counting the time to generate the input.

Comment: @YaGoi Root there was a bug in `2**np.arange(0,i).T` it produced the powers of 2 in inverse order. The correct code is `2**np.arange(i-1,-1,-1).T`. I edited the post.

Comment: @Colim This is clearly the best option (at least out of the ideas discussed so far) for quickly counting the frequencies. However, it seems to be assigning frequency counts to the wrong subsequence. for example, if I run it on the list in my OP, which is  
 `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`   
The outputs are:
`00:1  
01:1  
10:2  
11:1`  
These are the correct frequencies, however 01 should have 2 counts and 10 should have one count. I believe that `iBits` is grouping terms correctly, but the order changes at some step. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: @YaGoiRoot It's not clear what "generate the input" means. If it means generate the array, then it's unclear why you don't include that, since you should.

Comment: @YaGoi Root there was a bug that inverted the order. Is patched now. You mean `01` should have 2 counts and `10:1`

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark including some new solutions from me:

```
For i=2:
 2.9 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_NumPy
 3.7 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_count
 6.6 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_zip
 7.8 s ± 0.1 s  Colim_numpy
 8.4 s ± 0.0 s  Paul_genzip
 8.6 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_split2
10.5 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_slices2
10.6 s ± 0.1 s  Kelly_bytes_split1
16.1 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_slices1
20.9 s ± 0.1 s  constantstranger
45.1 s ± 0.3 s  original

For i=5:
 2.3 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_NumPy
 3.8 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_zip
 4.5 s ± 0.0 s  Paul_genzip
 4.5 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_split2
 5.2 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_split1
 5.4 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_slices2
 7.1 s ± 0.0 s  Colim_numpy
 7.2 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_slices1
 9.3 s ± 0.0 s  constantstranger
20.6 s ± 0.0 s  Kelly_bytes_count
25.3 s ± 0.1 s  original
```

This is for a list of length n=1e6, times multiplied by 100 so it somewhat reflects your timings with length 1e8. I minimally modified the other solutions so they do what your original does, i.e., take a list of ints and return a list of ints in the correct order. One or two of my slower solutions only work if the length is a multiple of their block size, I didn't bother making them work for all lengths since they're slower anyway.

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVbNbuM2EL77KdhDsaSsVSxnW2yEDVB0T0WBxR5yEwRBtimHtkxpRSqoN81D9RX6YukMSUlUogRFETTIQR7O7ze/zVnf1vLy8XHHS/I7r6pz/qU7fT1TEZKKJQsCfwW5JrKJyrY@bbqy5C3dnDVXtGIh0oXUH5lhVLpugLeIlPjOycUFESQgwj4hPU2QIxGZIZV1Sw5ESNIWcs9pHBLhDPYCVJFPn0jMyJ8ge5gIt1x3rUTznRTfOk5V6Gj5tu6kVtc3bcdZGmeRriuhNGWLxWIM8rto/BC3ugV7n1ESwsPHIBX4WbEsEIz5NtM74/oxJHfovapbzXcUNEQgcVKUsWxiyoCVq0psuYqf4tojaUEyPEBNMdzDUmRPQVqBNJe0YBcXIhCIWDbjv9XzZk6vX3Va7IGCSvZco/HAmqeHkEAEbCaCeLVaWecdsFPvt7eFkKbackxBsak4HcpC7GmRHpPj0irJ2PBiwnuGFNaoZbWcb5FKU2A@JhK8t8bmIdo4QtG2xZmm64xBX1BJlkRCHtlcN/itsEkPyzhJxDLOTBcdkr4LjCVbOqZsrFU0MLZYPq/UCqjlxjApE74y3xv87lWtMgDQfcegdtJ9aRFZLBTztcxWUlMJHc@DZiaFP0DkMDaetwhvnoE5YIyPAKzRAtiS9zA7/gW4s9BOa9L6sGGRiYOCoTeZCahs/f@A8pNpAoDlw9XV1VzbjUhNuwjNh8SKe7i9AulzWI/LA7Ss1QGfDmLnQ9Q1u0LzN8S4bsVeyKICZHtg923dNXxnal7DWMcZAmDAAHllcMB0JXbGlYbmlKTeN8MiAyU/XE84oG1GPBwxauqGPhVlvnc5xoQps6ENfM948rui6sym6LPnv7LIPlMnWbb8W447EIsLV@GMqgnSg4DD82vRVfmeS9yLqtsofOUSSoPD5pVbPrtELaOdC/YTIPY26yCcQXmOWv9rzre1VLqAxa9NGlsv9378kBkwtyZB30wbKJT2fNM1N/VvEjnugQI/k4Mt8ZDY32iey@4ECwlqtWnrXbfVFKolZmHLG17oa9hnDxYIf3JM9Ke6a2CdmfKD9c6yF6tvOJ/Mnhx70yGx7QHwOrIPMz1i1929ltHPcBOdcgingUsvAYV6nEGVPffsKOmX/K9CY7lVaSICWpkDD1dXFrVc3RYNp@/N/fYLXQeBEbZTAajmn0U3VpG91kJijzRryV1wxsbsFedHYun@UVd2cmuWmWHrez80v7w4LcErZUt4WjeW6l3CPsHb/z55UDZz8L30sJ55MDvyBTrwQ6njVUS0OHEiTg0OC/xeuO9a2fdtXVV8qwVE1rO5arTv2H66rqvh1dYvJAUvr5C44u7VGvRIoSBVVr5usAmgGB3DePwRywCAasiO2A4WTrzAeaF3/G6xwCUXr4Lg54WAr/VigUFgBu/LhKS2JUoscpPZB1OwqFLR0pWoqZxUX8gg5h8Nv/bGg1GXlhlLk8vpwVK@u0dPqFYs@RDF5QOcLH//Re6NY4Z66ajvAOvp8RSvvP5IN@RHmCLDuVSrqAO2XX2i0t1e/I8GkgC8X2rJh/4d4xobF5nQZzoes9BVXYX00l4HM7ywPfRIdiFHRdNwCRCMErC7nCtCGV@mi3r009ocHnmlnrAWSnFTLda3aydqkSq9BJj4QnLk52uTNwdc0wq8FV0mQ1JGeS6LE8/zkD0@/gM)):

```
def Kelly_NumPy(i, l):
    a = np.frombuffer(bytes(l), np.int8)
    stop = a.size // i * i
    s = a[:stop:i]
    for j in range(1, i):
        s = (s << 1) | a[j:stop:i]
    return np.unique(s, return_counts=True)[1].tolist()


def Kelly_zip(i, l):
    ctr = Counter(zip(*[iter(l)]*i))
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def Kelly_bytes_slices1(i, l):
    a = bytes(l)
    slices = [a[j:j+i] for j in range(0, len(a)//i*i, i)]
    ctr = Counter(slices)
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def Kelly_bytes_slices2(i, l):
    a = bytes(l)
    ig = itemgetter(*(slice(j, j+i) for j in range(0, 1000*i, i)))
    ctr = Counter(chain.from_iterable(
        ig(a[k:k+1000*i])
        for k in range(0, len(l), 1000*i)
    ))
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def Kelly_bytes_count(i, l):
    n = len(l)
    a = bytes(l)
    b = bytearray([2]) * (n + n//i)
    for j in range(i):
        b[j+1::i+1] = a[j::i]
    a = b
    ss = [bytes([2])]
    for _ in range(i):
        ss = [s+b for s in ss for b in [bytes([0]), bytes([1])]]
    return [a.count(s) for s in ss]


def Kelly_bytes_split1(i, l):
    n = len(l) // i
    stop = n * i
    a = bytes(l)
    sep = bytearray([2])
    b = sep * (stop + n - 1)
    for j in range(i):
        b[j::i+1] = a[j::i]
    ctr = Counter(bytes(b).split(sep))
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def Kelly_bytes_split2(i, l):
    n = len(l) // i
    stop = n * i
    a = bytes(l)
    sep = bytearray([2])
    b = sep * (5000*i + 4999)
    ctr = Counter()
    for k in range(0, stop, 5000*i):
        for j in range(i):
            b[j::i+1] = a[k+j:k+5000*i+j:i]
        ctr.update(bytes(b).split(sep))
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def original(i,l):
    grouped = [str(l[k:k + i]) for k in range(0, len(l), i)] 
    if len(grouped[len(grouped) - 1]) != len(grouped[0]):
        grouped.pop(len(grouped) - 1)
    grouped_sort = sorted(grouped) 
    grouped_sort_values = Counter(grouped_sort).values() 
    freq_list = list(grouped_sort_values)
    return freq_list


def Paul_genzip(subseq_len, sequence):
    ctr = Counter(subseq for subseq in zip(*[iter(sequence)] * subseq_len))
    return [v for k, v in sorted(ctr.items())]


def constantstranger(i,l):
    freq_list = [0] * 2 ** i
    binaryTupToInt = {binTup:j for j, binTup in enumerate(product((0,1),repeat=i))}
    c = Counter(binaryTupToInt[tuple(l[k:k+i])] for k in range(0, len(l) // i * i, i))
    for k, v in c.items():
        freq_list[k] = v
    return freq_list


def Colim_numpy(i: int, l):
    l = np.array(l)
    iBits = l[:i*(l.size//i)].reshape(-1, i)@(2**np.arange(i-1,-1,-1).T)
    unique, counts = np.unique(iBits, return_counts=True)
    return counts.tolist()


funcs = [
    original,
    Colim_numpy,
    Paul_genzip,
    constantstranger,
    Kelly_NumPy,
    Kelly_bytes_count,
    Kelly_zip,
    Kelly_bytes_slices1,
    Kelly_bytes_slices2,
    Kelly_bytes_split1,
    Kelly_bytes_split2,
]

from time import time
import os
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat, chain, product
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter 
from statistics import mean, stdev

n = 10**6
i = 2

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t/n*1e8 for t in sorted(times[f])[:3]]
    return f'{mean(ts):4.1f} s ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} s '

for _ in range(10):
    l = [b % 2 for b in os.urandom(n)]
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
        t = time()
        result = f(i, l)
        t = time() - t
        times[f].append(t)
        if expect is None:
             expect = result
        else:
            assert result == expect

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__,)
```

Comment: Returning `np.unique` as list has a bug, when not all string were found, the list do not carry information on what strings were counted. I wrote a patch on my second answer.

Comment: @Colim Yes, I know. But that's a rather obvious potential issue, and the OP's solution has it as well, so I'm assuming they're aware of it and it's not an issue for them. Maybe because that is practically impossible with their large amount of data, or maybe because "missing" ones don't matter for them. In any case, this reflects the question's reference implementation, and your patch deviates from it, so in that sense you didn't fix a bug but introduced one.

Comment: @KellyBundy Hi, sorry to follow up several months later, but I've noticed an issue with this method, in that it doesn't function for sequences of certain lengths (I believe you mention it in your post). for example, with a sequence of 8192 digits, the following error is raised: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2730,) (2731,) ` Is there an easy way around this issue?

Comment: @YaGoiRoot Which one of the methods are you talking about, and with what value of `i`?

Comment: @KellyBundy The `Kelly_NumPy(i, l)` function for `i=8192`.

Comment: @YaGoiRoot Can't reproduce, [works for me](https://tio.run/##ZVC7bsMwDNz1FVwKSIXhwOmSGskXFCg6dDOMwG6khoEkqnoMKvrvruTGUzkRxzvekS7HK9mnZblIBS9S63x@TeYtc2xAi55BqQlOYF2rPJk5KSU9n3OUgWvRVBxtPIiVGCK5wp3agN8SdjtAeAT8G1V86Cujx3GFFHm4AVrwk/2UvGsA74abgAc4HqET8FO0t34TehmTt9U6WfxKkofmjp0/KNkYTu8@STF0YxtJY4hcMIbGkY9AYetsMi7DFMqeMi1uh@55z3RphhkeYL/mm2s@Cm0qGS9keOWIkTlfjub/3iWW5Rc).

Comment: @KellyBundy huh interesting, I'll look into this further. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @YaGoiRoot Did you maybe actually use `i = 3`? That does give me that error. My `a[j::i]` should be `a[j:stop:i]`. I'll edit later, can't right now.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure I understood that last part about the order. It seems unnecessary to build a giant list of subsequences. Use a generator to yield the subsequences to the counter - that way you also don't have to fiddle with indices:

```
from collections import Counter


def count_subsequences(sequence, subseq_len=2):
    return Counter(subseq for subseq in zip(*[iter(sequence)] * subseq_len))

sequence = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
counter = count_subsequences(sequence)

for subseq in (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1):
    print("{}: {}".format(subseq, counter[subseq]))
```

Output:

```
(0, 0): 1
(0, 1): 2
(1, 0): 1
(1, 1): 1
>>>
```

In this case, the function returns the counter object itself, and the calling code displays the results in some order.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to argue for the need to build a giant list of subsequences. The reason that I have the output in its current form is so that the function which this one feeds into could iterate through the frequencies of each subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is much faster. It uses Kelly's idea of using `numpy.frombuffer` instead of converting the list to numpy array, and uses Pandas to count unique values, which is faster than `numpy.unique` for more than 100 000 results

```
import pandas as pd

def subseq_counter(i: int, l):
    l = np.frombuffer(bytes(l), np.int8)
    iBits = l[:i*(l.size//i)].reshape(-1, i)@(2 **np.arange(i-1, -1, -1).T).astype(np.int8)
    # bug fix: when not enough data, (higly probable for large i),
    # iBits do not has every possible value, so returning unique values
    # as list may lose information
    answer = [0]*2**i  # empty counter including all possible values
    if len(iBits) > 100000:
        for i, v in pd.value_counts(iBits).items():
            answer[i] = v
    else:
        unique, count = np.unique(iBits, return_counts=True)
        for i, v in zip(unique, count):
            answer[i] = v
    return answer
```

Comment: If `np.unique` wins for up to 200000, then for larger lengths it might be faster to work in chunks smaller than that, solving each with `np.unique` and combining the results.

Comment: Regarding your *"higly probable for large i"*: "large i" for them means i=5 (see the comments under the question). And they have *"sequences of lengths near 15 billion"*, and they're *"the output of a quantum physics experiment"* (which makes me think of randomness), and their own solution ignores this rather obvious potential issue. So I'd say it's rather extremely *improbable*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

def subseq_counter(i,l):
    freq_list = [0] * 2 ** i
    binaryTupToInt = {binTup:j for j, binTup in enumerate(product((0,1),repeat=i))}
    c = Counter(binaryTupToInt[tuple(l[k:k+i])] for k in range(0, len(l) // i * i, i))
    for k, v in c.items():
        freq_list[k] = v
    return freq_list

l = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
i = 2
print(subseq_counter(i, l))
```

Ouput:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Notes:

- Using the above code and changing `i` to `3` gives:

  ```
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
  ```

  This is showing the frequency for all possible binary values of length `3` in ascending order beginning with `0` (binary `0,0,0`) and ending with `7` (binary `1,1,1`). In other words, `0,0,0` occurs `0` times, `0,0,1` occurs `1` time, `0,1,0` occurs `1` time, `0,1,1` occurs `0` times, etc., through `1,1,1` which occurs `0` times.
- Using the code in the question with `i` changed to `3` gives:

  ```
  [1, 1, 1]
  ```

  This output seems hard to decipher, as it isn't labeled so that we can easily see that the results with a non-zero value correspond to the 3-digit binary values `0,0,1`, `0,1,0` and `1,1,0`.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a benchmark of several approaches on an input list of length 55 million (with `i` set to `2`) including OP's, counting sort (this answer), numpy including list-to-ndarray conversion overhead, and numpy without the overhead:

```
foo_1 output:
[10000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000]
foo_2 output:
[10000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000]
foo_3 output:
[10000000 15000000 15000000 15000000]
foo_4 output:
[10000000 15000000 15000000 15000000]
Timeit results:
foo_1 (OP) ran in 32.20719700001064 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_2 (counting sort) ran in 17.91718759998912 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_3 (numpy with list-to-array conversion) ran in 9.713831000000937 seconds using 1 iterations
foo_4 (numpy) ran in 1.695262699999148 seconds using 1 iterations
```

The clear winner is `numpy`, though unless the calling program can easily be changed to use ndarrays, the required conversion slows things down by a factor of about 5x in this example.

Comment: Why the detour with conversion to an int? Instead of having the Counter count the tuples.

Comment: The conversion to int allows us to avoid calling `sort()` and instead simply populate `freq_list` from Counter. I have done the int conversion first then populated the Counter, but it could just as easily be done later when populating `freq_list`.

Comment: Ah, that somewhat makes sense. But I'm quite confident it would be more efficient to simply sort the Counter keys (being tuples) instead.